# Exposing entity CRUD for DI without breaking DDD Aggregate principles

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I have a repository for an aggregate: `Order` and `OrderRepository`. `Order` has `Products`, `Customer`, etc. I'm using a micro ORM called dapper and .net core.

Here is my issue, when I need to save, I don't see how I can't break some DDD principle. I would like to have repositories for child entities of the aggregate i.e. `ProductRepository`, `CustomerRepository` and when I save the order it uses those repositories to save child entities but I understand that you can only have one repo per aggregate. I decided to just make a class called `ProductPersistor`,  that would be `internal` to my infrastructure class library and called by the `OrderRepository` however then I can't use DI as it's configured .NET Core's DI framework in a different project. Furthermore it's still accessible by the classes in that class library. I can add all the insert update of all child entities into `OrderRepository` but that would be a gross SRP issue and still can't be injected using a DI container.

With regards to queries, the same issue stands although with dapper I can write a massive SQL JOIN and split it into different entities although that's not very efficient or flexible though.

I feel like I'm missing something. Can someone help?

Edit: As the comments below pointed out, Product and Customer can be their own Aggregate root. So let's replace those with Order and OrderLineItem.

Comment: Product is not a child of Order.  OrderLineItem would be.

Comment: Yeah I just read about that so what if I replaced products with OrderLineItem, the question still stands. How do I create an injectable class to delete / add / update order line items without allowing direct access to the consumer so they have to go through the order AR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Product` and `Customer` seem like aggregates on their own, so they will need to have their own repositories `ProductRepository` and `CustomerRepository`. They should not be child entities of `Order`.
- Your `Order` aggregate would be linked to `Product` and `Customer`, and the best way to do it between aggregates is to link on their unique identifiers.
- A `Repository` is not equal or same as the underlying table - at least that is what DDD recommends. The Repository pattern sits between the aggregate data structure and the table/document structure, and represents the domain side of things. It's methods usually represent valid domain concepts: `GetCompletedOrders()`, `GetTotalTaxAmount()`, and so on.
- An Application Service is supposed to handle the task of loading/persisting aggregates with the help of repositories, and that's the place where you would handle multiple repositories required for a process. This is where you can query other aggregates and get their identifiers, if necessary.
- But I wouldn't recommend using multiple repositories as part of a single transaction in an Application Service. It violates the guideline that each business transaction should touch at most one aggregate. All other aggregates should be updated via Domain Events - they should become eventually consistent. Good for scaling and performance, this way. In your case, you may update `Order` aggregate, and bubble domain events to update `Product` and `Customer`, if necessary.
- If you have complex queries and expect to run into performance problems (which I think you will as your system scales between `Order`, `Product`, and `Customer`), I would suggest you explore CQRS as an option. You don't have to implement it fully, but have readily available "Read" models in the background, with data already constructed in the format you want to consume. Background workers populate these "Read" models on a near real-time basis.

Please ask if this explanation does not cover all your questions or doubts.

Comment: Great! Thanks that's very informative. So in my example I mentioned products and orders but what if I was talking about order and order line items? I want to update the order line items through the order AR. As far as I know the repository is the way to reach the persistence layer even if it represents the domain. How would I update or delete the order line items (I would like to do it outside the OrderRepository because SRP and I want to be able to inject the dependency) without breaking the ddd abstraction where we only want to allow consumers to add or delete order items through the AR?

Comment: I like to think Repositories are one layer above Data Access Objects (DAOs). Repositories gather concrete DAO objects (one per table) and DB connections to execute queries and persist objects. If `OrderLine` items are entities within `Order` aggregate, you would still have one `OrderRepository` which would persist and retrieve all items together. That's the only way to ensure you satisfy all invariant boundaries.

Comment: Thanks! Marked as answer

Comment: and the DAO can be accessed by the DI framework in another project even if at that point I can bypass the Aggregate root and update objects directly?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, although I would suggest you do all you can to *not* bypass the Aggregate. Things like that tend to grow over time, and updates from different sources will mean you don't have one set of business rules active at all time.